# Compare nested lists using scala test

Tags: scala, scalatest

How do I compare two list of lists using scala test?

```
val actual = Array(Row("1", "2"), Row("3", "4"))
val fail_expected = Array(Row("1", "2"), Row("3", "2"))
val pass_expected = Array(Row("3", "4"), Row("1", "2"))
```

I have tried with

```
actual should contain theSameElementsAs pass_expected
```

but it is not working, it says that the two arrays are different, when they are actually the same.

I am using funsuite with scala test.

Comment: convert the array to List i.e. `val actual = List(Row("1", "2"), Row("3", "4"))`

Answer (score 2):

See [working with containers](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers#workingWithContainers).  You need to implement equality for the element i.e. `Row` class by either:

- The standard Scala way, like:

  ```
  class Row(val elems: String*) {

      def canEqual(other: Any): Boolean = other.isInstanceOf[Row]

      override def equals(other: Any): Boolean = other match {
        case that: Row =>
          (that canEqual this) &&
            elems == that.elems
        case _ => false
      }

      override def hashCode(): Int = {
        val state = Seq(elems)
        state.map(_.hashCode()).foldLeft(0)((a, b) => 31 * a + b)
      }
  }
  object Row {
      def apply(elems: String*) = new Row(elems: _*)
  }
  ```

  or simply make it a case class:

  ```
  case class Row(elems: String*)
  ```
- Or provide an implicit `Equality[Row]` implementation:

  ```
  import org.scalactic.Equality
  implicit object RowEquals extends Equality[Row] {
      override def areEqual(a: Row, b: Any): Boolean = b match {
        case r: Row => a.elems == r.elems
        case _ => false
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

A quick but not the best solution is converting arrays into strings. You can achieve it by using `mkstring` method:

In short:

```
 actual.mkstring(",") == pass_expected.mkstring(",")
```